# Are Virus/rootkits via ubuntu updates possible?

Tags: updates, malware, rootkit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is the system kept secure?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28069/how-is-the-system-kept-secure)
>   [What security policies exist in place for packages and scripts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172077/what-security-policies-exist-in-place-for-packages-and-scripts)

I fear that just like on Windows there might be ways to catch a malware/virus/rootkit via the (automatic) system updates. What are the changes?

Is it for instance possible that a "man in the middle" will sniff my network traffic and can see what I am doing (updating) and then fake a response to me that in fact is a trojan?

Does Ubuntu Canonical do anything to make sure that the files/programms/software from their servers is not tampered with?

I fear that Linux is quite unsecure and most often the safety is just more an illusion and not substantially better then other os, like windows. Given that most Linux users are a tiny little bit more likely to be computer-intelligent most malware will most likely be just hidden better?

Anyhow the question is how and where to look for the options to make sure I do not loose system security because a man in the middle is there in the system update of ubuntu.

Being abroad quite often and using many open wifis in unsecure countries USA,China I only helped myself using a tunnel VPN and updating from a virutal access in my home country. Still internet routing I will never be sure so how is update secured?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/28069

Comment: Thank you for the comments! It is surely targeting the same broad topic "system security" sure. My focus is again said on the update process and to understand a little more what is used to make it safe. I would assume that checksums and encryption is some way to make the update process secure over an insecure channel (internet). For this issue I cannot find a solution in the otherwise very nice, suggested question